# Using square brackets for the column attribute in a Hibernate Mapping File

Tags: xml, hibernate

Do [ ] around a column name in a hibernate mapping file mean anything?

Ex.

```
<property name="tableCol" column="[TABLE_col]" not-null="false" type="long" unique="false" optimistic-lock="true" lazy="false" generated="never" />
```

vs

```
<property name="tableCol" column="TABLE_col" not-null="false" type="long" unique="false" optimistic-lock="true" lazy="false" generated="never" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[]` around a column name is used when you want to use a database reserved keyword as column name.

Example :

If you have a column named `DESC` which is a database reserved keyword, it will cause a `JDBCException` if you try with :

```
<property name="tableCol" type="string" >
    <column name="DESC" type="long" not-null="false" />
</property>
```

You must use :

```
<property name="tableCol" type="string" >
    <column name="[DESC]" type="long" not-null="false" />
</property>
```